# Access information from a previous Kubeflow component

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a `ModelBatchPredictOp` component in my pipeline. This component generates 3 artifacts: `batchpredictionjob`, `big_query_table`, and `gcs_output_directory`. The pipeline is running fine.

What I need is a way to access the `tableId` property of artifact `big_query_table`, so I can use it in the next component (a `BigqueryQueryJobOp`).

That is what I want:
[image: Here you will find an image of what I want]

The URI information would be good as well since it contains the full path for the created table and I can extract the desired part.

This is my 2nd component which is creating the batch prediction and the 3rd component which should consume the previous outputs.

```
# Component to do the batch prediction
batch_predict_op = ModelBatchPredictOp(
   project=project_id, 
   location=DEFAULT_VERTEX_REGION, 
   instances_format = 'bigquery',
   predictions_format = 'bigquery',
   model=importer_spec.outputs['artifact'],
   job_display_name='teste_batch_predict',
   bigquery_source_input_uri=f'bq://{input_data_table_ref}',
   bigquery_destination_output_uri= f'bq://{output_bq}',
   ).after(input_data_table_op)

   top_predictions_table_ref = f'{project_id}.{bigquery_dataset}.test'
        
# Component to create the table based on previous component
top_predictions_op = bq.BigqueryQueryJobOp(
   project_id,
   location = bigquery_job_location,
   query = predict_dataset.get_query(
   output_table = top_predictions_table_ref,
   source_table = batch_predict_op.outputs['bigquery_output_table'],
   query_name = 'query_top_100.sql',
   DEBUG = DEBUG)
   ).after(batch_predict_op)
```